# Symfony3 validation error: This value is not valid

Tags: php, symfony

When I updated from Symfony 2 to 3 and tried to save the data from the form, I got a validation error that the author is not valid.
However, the author was an int type and was the same as in Symfony2.
I don't understand why I get a validation error. Is there anything you can think of?
The major change during the update was the change from the choice list to the choice loader.
It does not seem that validation is set for Entity and formtype as well.

```
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation {#2601 ▼
  -message: "Not a valid value."
  -messageTemplate: "This value is not valid."
  -parameters: [▼
    "{{ value }}" => "0"
  ]
  -plural: null
  -root: Symfony\Component\Form\Form {#1763 ▶}
  -propertyPath: "children[author]"
  -invalidValue: "0"
  -constraint: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\Constraints\Form {#1963 …}
  -code: "1dafa156-89e1-4736-b832-419c2e501fca"
  -cause: Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException {#1927 …}
```

ArticleType.php

```php
        $authorChoiceList = new StaffChoiceLoader($this->staffService, 
$options['login_staff']);
        $builder->add("author", EntityType::class, array(
            "required" => true,
            "class" => "AppBundle:Staff",
            "choice_loader" => $authorChoiceList,
        ));
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            "validation_groups" => function (FormInterface $form) {
                $article = $form->getData();
                return $this->getValidationGroups($article->getArticleStatus());
            },
        ));
    }
    protected function getValidationGroups($articleStatus)
    {
        return $this->articleService->getValidationGroups($articleStatus);
    }
```

ChoiceLoader

```php
    public function setCurrentStaff($currentStaff)
    {
        $this->currentStaff = $currentStaff;
    }

    public function loadChoiceList($value = null)
    {
        $staffs = $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop());

        if ($this->currentStaff && !array_search($this->currentStaff, $staffs)) {
            $staffs[] = $this->currentStaff;
        }
            return new arrayChoiceList($staffs, null);
    }

    public function loadChoicesForValues(array $values, $value = null)
    {
        if (empty($choices))
        {
            return array();
        }

        $values = array();
        foreach ($choices as $person)
        {
            $values[] = (string) $this->loginStaff->getId();
        }

        return $values;
    }

    public function loadValuesForChoices(array $choices, $value = null)
    {
        if (empty($values))
        {
            return array();
        }

        return $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop());
    }
```

Article.php

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Staff")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $author;

    /**
     * @param \AppBundle\Model\Entity\Staff $author
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setAuthor(\AppBundle\Model\Entity\Staff $author = null)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \AppBundle\Model\Entity\Staff
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify which version of Symfony 2 you were using, but it could be related to this.

https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices-as-values

Long story short, choices_as_values as been introduced in Symfony 2.7, since Symfony 3.0 this is now the default behavior, so you might need to array_flip the authorChoiceList.

This is just a guess.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
Certainly it seems possible.
What should array_flip be used for? Is it ```$authorChoiceList```?

Comment: array_flip — Exchanges all keys with their associated values in an array https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Comment: I did ```array_flip``` for ```$staffs```. The options displayed were switched to numbers, but the result was also a validation error.